# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker'

Tags: c#, http, owin, azure-web-app-service

I have App Service using .NET Framework 4.6.1 (web application that exposes some REST endpoints) that is hosted in Azure.
From time to time I get this error in production ( never on internal environment ).

```
Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker'. Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker'. 

System.ObjectDisposedException:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.CheckDisposed (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter+<InvokeCore>d__0.MoveNext (System.Web.Http.Owin, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage+<RunApp>d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
```

The error appears on multiple endpoints and from the logs it is issued on this call:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, fileInfoResponse);
```

Any idea why this happens? I have checked and

Comment: I wonder if this could happen if the client disconnects while the file transfer is occurring?